# Writing a class in an asynchronous way or just calling it asynchronously

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, backgroundworker

I want to create **a class that represents a long running operation**.

**This class:**

1. Should be constructed with some parameters,
2. It should run the operation by calling a method,
3. It should report its progress and it should report the end of the operation.

I have used `BackgroundWorker` before but I don't have any direct experience with `Thread`s or `Task`s, and I need to use .NET 3.5 so no `async`-`await`.

One way to do it is to couple the class with a `BackgroundWorker`. So the user will pass a `BackgroundWorker` to the class and the class will raise that `BackgroundWorker`s events. But I'm not sure if it would be good design.

The other way is to create the class, so that it will have its own events for progress change, progress end, and so on. The `BackgroundWorker` will be in the so called *bootstrapper*, and the `BackgroundWorker`s events will be connected to the class' events. But this seems like an unnecessary level of abstraction.

What is the usual way of designing these kinds of classes. Is it better to write it as a sort of ***asynchronous*** class, or is it better to write it in a normal way and just call it ***asynchronously***?

**Summary:** In the comments, MikeCorcoran summarized the question beautifully; I am wondering "*whether to write the class so it automatically does its work asynchronously within each method, or write the class so it works synchronously but is designed to be run on a background thread.*"

Comment: Do you mean write a method in a calls that can be called asynchronously?

Comment: @Anon no i think he means whether to write the class so it automatically does its work asynchronously within each method, or write the class so it works synchronously but is designed to be run on a background thread.

Comment: @Anon, I'm sorry I didn't quite understand you. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MikeCorcoran, precisely. Honestly you just summarized the whole question in one sentence better than me explaining it in six paragraphs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is, "it depends."

If there's nothing in the code that requires it to use multiple threads or to operate asynchronously, then you should write it as a normal method (or class). That way, you can test it synchronously, or even use it synchronously in simple programs. That you elect to call it from a `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task` or some other way shouldn't matter.

Always do things in the simplest way you can, and still meet the design goals. If what the class does isn't inherently asynchronous, then don't force it to be.

Comment: But what would be a class that is inherently asynchronous? Please forgive my ignorance, I am just trying to understand how I can decide which one to choose. What is the point of writing an asynchronous class? As far as I can imagine, pretty much anything can be called asynchronously.

Comment: @hattenn: For example, a class that implements a multithreaded sort. The point of my answer was that you should write the class to do what it does. You shouldn't have to think about whether its methods will be called synchronously or asynchronously, or whether instances of the type will be used by a single thread or multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks @Jim, it makes more sense now.